# What is a super constructor?

Tags: java

```
public class HalloGUI extends JFrame{
    
    public HelloGUI(String title)
    { 
     // Some explanation about this method 
     super (title);
     /*Why super(title)? What is the usage of super() */

     /* Here some other codes */
    }
    
}
```

I don't understand the usage of `super(title);`. I know that title is a parameter of the method super(), but why does ine use it? Do you really need to use it? What is the function of `super(title);` in this code?

Comment: `super(titel)` will call the constructor `JFrame(String)` . If that call wasn't there it would call `JFrame()` without a title.

Comment: Please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html. It's worth noting that Stack Overflow isn't really a good place to learn fundamental language concepts - I'd recommend a good book for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet hi Tnx for replying!! Could you please recommend me (name me) a good book ?

Comment: @M.Deinum tnx for respounding ! I really appraciate you !

Comment: Make up your mind. `titel` or `title`? This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've read any Java books I'm afraid, but there are a *lot* available, so I'd have a look around and read reviews.

Comment: 'super(titel)' is a method which calls the constructor JFrame(String)`  with titel. am i right ?

Comment: That is correct, but only because that's what you're extending